# How can I detect if the user scrolls to end of an <embed> element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, scroll

How can I detect if the user scrolls to end of an `<embed>` element?

```
<embed src="contract.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="800" height="800" id="contractPDF">
```

I used this code but it doesn't work:

```
$('#contractPDF').bind('scroll', function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {   
    alert("end reched");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to know where your element begins and where it ends, so that when you scroll down, you know if you already pass that point.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {

    // Fetch the embed container.
    var container = $('#contractPDF');

    // Height of our window.
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  
  // Container information.
  var containerHeight = $(container).height();
  var containerBottom = container.offset().top + containerHeight;

    // Location of our window in our page.
    var windowLocation = $(this).scrollTop();

   // Check if we are past it.
   if (windowLocation + windowHeight > containerBottom) { 
    alert('reached');
   }

});
```

```css
#contractPDF {
  height: 900px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  position:relative;
  display:block;
}

#contractPDF2 {
  height: 900px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  position:relative;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contractPDF"></div>
<div id="contractPDF2"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for your help , the code doesn't detect even the scroll of the window

Comment: Weird I have always done it like that. You have it inside a `jQuery(document).ready(function() {})` clause right?

Comment: I updated my code and add it inside a snippet so that you can try it. It is working now, so it should work on your project as well.